# A compact T1 topological space has a proper dense subset to which it is homeomorphic. What can be said about the space?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact T1 (so singleton subsets are closed) topological space. Suppose that there is a *proper* subset $D \subset X$ such that:

- $D$ is dense in $X$;
- $D$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

Note that $X$ is then *not* a compactification of $D$, since $D$, being homeomorphic to $X$, is already compact.

**My questions:**

(**1**) What can be said about $X$?

(**2**) Can anything be said about $X$ if either of the compactness or T1 conditions is dropped?

Comment: Could you be more specific? "What can be said" is open-ended.

Comment: This is the very first question I've posted, so please forgive any ambiguity in how I framed the question. I mean, is there a characterization of spaces with this property? My feeling is that perhaps the conditions are too general to say very much at all, but I'm looking for general insight in how to go about answering the question as much as I am looking for a specific answer.

Comment: Well, it would then be useful if you say more about what you could think of so far, e.g. trivial remarks and a few examples.

Comment: You might be interested to look into the concept of a "Z-set" in infinite dimensional topology. A Z-set is a closed subspace Z of Hilbert space s such that s-Z is homeomorphic to s via a homeomorphism that moves points an arbitrarily small distance.

Comment: (Except that Hilbert spaces aren't compact.)

Comment: Also posted on MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326572/a-possibly-t1-topological-space-has-a-dense-subset-which-is-homeomorphic-to-th

Comment: Obvious comment: $X$ can't be Hausdorff, for then the compact subset $D$ would be closed.

Comment: An example:  Take any compact space   with a non-isolated point $x_0$, and replace $x_0$ by infinitely many copies. - This example suggests the following (still fuzzy) question:  If $X$ is a space as required, can you always find a continuous image $Y$ which is  compact Hausdorff, where the map $f:X\to Y$ has small (in some sense) fibers?

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that much of anything can be said.  Note that given any non-compact example, you can get a compact example by adjoining a point whose neighborhoods are the cofinite sets, and I suspect that in many cases you can compactify in other ways as well (in fact, I believe there is always a canonical finest 1-point compactification such that $X\cup\{\infty\}$ is still homeomorphic to $D\cup\{\infty\}$).